# How to vectorize this pytorch code over (at least) the batch dimension?

Tags: python, vectorization, pytorch

I want to implement a code to build an adjacency matrix such that (for example):

If X[0] : [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0], then,

```
A[0, 1] = 1
A[1, 2] = 1
A[2, 0] = 1
A[0, 1] = 1
A[1, 0] = 1
```

The following code works fine, however, it's too slow! So, please help me to vectorize this code on the batch (first) dimension at least:

```
A = torch.zeros((3, 3, 3), dtype = torch.float)
X = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1], [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1]])
for a, x in zip(A, X):
    for i, j in zip(x, x[1:]):
        a[i, j] = 1
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In order to get the best experience for both you as someone asking a question, and also future visitors to your post, please consider updating your question in accordance to [ask]. Specifically, indicate what the *goal* of your piece of code is (*what should it do?*), what you have tried so far (*why is this not optimal?*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that there is a much simpler way of doing this, but I tried to keep within the realm of `torch` function calls, to make sure that any gradient operation could be properly tracked.

In case this is not required for backpropagation, I strongly suggest you look into solution that maybe utilize some numpy functions, because I think there is a stronger guarantee to find something suitable here. But, without further ado, here is the solution I came up with.

It essentially transforms your `X` vector into a series of tuple entries that correspond to the position in `A`. For this, we need to align some of the indices (specifically, the first dimension is only implicitly given in `X`, since the first list in `X` corresponds to `A[0,:,:]`, the second list to `A[1,:,:]`, and so on.
This is also probably where you can start optimizing the code, because I did not find a reasonable description of such a matrix, and therefore had to come up with my own way of creating it.

```
# Start by "aligning" your shifted view of X
# Essentially, take the all but the last element, 
# and put it on top of all but the first element.
X_shift = torch.stack([X[:,:-1], X[:,1:]], dim=2)
# X_shift.shape: (3,5,2) in your example

# To assign this properly, we need to turn it into a "concatenated" list,
# where each entry corresponds to a 2D tuple in the respective dimension of A.
temp_tuples = X_shift.view(-1,2).transpose(0,1)
# temp_tuples.shape: (2,15) in your example. Below are the values:
tensor([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
        [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1]])

# Now we have to create a matrix do indicate the proper "first dimension index"
fix_dims = torch.repeat_interleave(torch.arange(0,3,1), len(X[0])-1, 0).unsqueeze(dim=0)
# fix_dims.shape: (1,15)
# Long story short, this creates the following vector.
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
# Note that the unsqueeze is necessary to properly concatenate the two matrices:
access_tuples = tuple(torch.cat([fix_dims, temp_tuples], dim=0))
A[access_tuples] = 1
```

This further assumes that every dimension in X has the same number of tuples changed. If that is not the case, then you have to manually create a `fix_dims` vector, where each increment is repeated the length of `X[i]` times. If it is equal as in your example, you can safely use the proposed solution.

Answer (score -1):

Make `X` a tuple instead of a tensor:

```
A = torch.zeros((3, 3, 3), dtype = torch.float)
X = ([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1], [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1])
A[X] = 1
```

For example, by casting it like this: `A[tuple(X)]`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the correct result. In fact, if you run the posted sample code, you will notice that the inner loop additionally shifts the index and alters a 2D position, instead of simply accessing the respective indices in each dimension. E.g., the "first" dimensions will be flipped to `1`s at the following positions: `[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2,0), (0,1), (1,0)]`.

Comment: Could you then please give an example of the output and clarify things more in the question?

Comment: Sure! Thanks! :)